# не подключается bower component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

Хочу подключить файл локализации `angular-i18n` с помощью bower. Когда добавляю скрипт с путем на файл `.js` все работает, но после перезагрузки сервера подключенный скрипт удаляется.
json bower'a:

```
{
  "name": "some_name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.15",
    "angular-bootstrap": "0.12.1",
    "angular-cookies": ">=1.2.*",
    "angular-dialog-service": "5.2.8",
    "angular-i18n": "~1.4.1",
.....
```

ошибка в консоли при поднятии сервера :

```
angular-i18n was not injected in your file
```

подключаю в `index.html`

```
<!-- bower:js -->
<script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/angular-i18n/angular-locale_ru-ru.js"></script>
....
<!-- endbower -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular-i18n не подключается через wiredep. Вынесите подключение `angular-locale_ru-ru.js` за скобки `<!-- bower:js --><!-- endbower -->` иначе он будет удаляться постоянно.

Comment: спасибо! подскажите, нужно ли в таком случае помещать angular-i18n в какие-то другие скобки? к примеру `<!-- build:js({client,node_modules}) app/vendor.js -->`. я совсем зеленый в этой теме

Comment: В вендорский не желательно - упадет :) Если вы пользуетесь стандартным шаблоном, то vendor.js идет выше чем angular.js от которого зависит angular-locale_ru-ru.js